# PDF Form Field Contents not displayed

Tags: javascript, firefox, pdf, pdf-generation, pdf.js

I generate PDFs with form fields programmatically using Apache PDFBox (Java). However, when loading the PDF with PDF.JS/Firefox, the content of those fields is not displayed. When opening the files with a standalone viewer or Chrome, the content of that fields is displayed correctly.

I know that PDF.JS doesn't support editing AcroForms, but I read that just displaying shouldn't be any problem.

Here is a generated PDF that isn't displayed correctly with PDF.JS/Firefox:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B197M5cYPdP4U2hhV1U2UURpSE0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How did you generate the PDF? Could you share a sample code? Which version of PDFBox did you use?
The reason there is nothing displayed is that although the value for the form field has been set the didn't make it into the appearance stream i.e. it's nearly empty. The appearance stream is what is used for displaying the fields content.

Comment: The PDF was generated by LibreOffice 4.2.8.2 (File -> Export as PDF). Then the fields were set by PDFBox. But I also tried to fill the form with LibreOffice and the content is not shown either... So I assume that the problem is related to the PDF generation with LibreOffice. Currently I am trying to generate the PDF with another application (Acrobat DC Pro).

Comment: OpenOffice / LibreOffice tends to export PDFs with the **NeedAppearances** flag set to true; this asks the PDF viewer to generate appearances. PDF processors filling-in such PDFs often react to that flag by not creating appearances themselves; the PDF viewer, after all, is asked to generate appearances anyways. Unfortunately, though, numerous incomplete PDF viewers don't know how to generate appearances. Thus, they ignore the flag and show what they find: no appearances.

Comment: Prior to setting the field value please set the NeedAppearances flag to false. PDFBox 2.0.x doesn't create an appearance stream if the flag is set to true. 2.1.x will change that and always generate an appearance stream regardless of the flag being true or false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to set the flag "NeedAppearances" to false as mkl and Maruan Sahyoun mentioned in the comments. Thanks.

```
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = _pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
acroForm.setNeedAppearances(false);
```